# While Debugging IIS from VS2008 Website Is Unresponsive

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis, application-pool

I have a web app running in a local instance of IIS 7.5.  My app pool has it Maximum Worker PROCESSES at 3.  When I go to Vs2008 and attach my debugger to my local IIS I see three w3wp.exe processes as expected.  I attach to all three.  When I run a web page my breakpoint hits in my code behind, as expected.

Here's the problem: in my code behind my C# code is calling a service on another computer that in turn sends a request back to my local IIS box.  This is all synchronous.  The problem is that while I'm in the debugger it seems like that remote code's call to my IIS box is immediately failing.  If I go on to that remote box while I'm debugging and try to pull up any URL from my local box it hangs.  And, as soon as I hit F5 in VS2008 the browser frees up and fulfills the request.

So why does the VS2008 debugger cause IIS to not use any of the other worker processes to service other incomming requests?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

While you debugging any process - **all** the threads hangs.

So what you're describing is expected behavior. You're debugging a thread in IIS, the whole process hangs until you press F5 and return the control to the process.

Comment: I think my choice of wording above might be confusing things. Let me re-state: my "Maximium Worker PROCESSES" setting in the app pool is 3.  So there are three EXE's running (w3wp.exe) that I can attach to.  So, first off, if I"m debugging a PROCESS then I'm not sure why the other two processes aren't serving up the second request.  Secondly, I don't understand what you mean when you say stopping a thread stops the entire process.  I've done a lot of multi-threaded development and that's certain not that case. You can freeze and thaw threads through in the VS debugger.

Comment: I mean that when you stopping on a breakpoint, all other threads not running in the background.